# How to avoid the native full screen video with HTML5 on iphone

Tags: react-native

We are using
    `react-native: 0.59.9`,
    `react-native-wkwebview-reborn: ^2.0.0`,
and loading the `WKWebView` Component like this:

```
<WKWebView
          source={{
            file: RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath+'/ICFPackage/ICFPackage/index.html',
            allowingReadAccessToURL: RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath
          }}

          originWhitelist={'["*"]'}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          onLoad={() => this.sendPostMessage()}
          allowFileAccess={true}
          allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
          allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
          allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
        />
```

Since `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` is unsupported by `wkwebview` video is taking full screen while playing, Kindly guide me how to support the  `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` in `wkwebview`.